# Svelte export malfunction

Tags: javascript, web, import, svelte, sveltekit

I am trying to export constants to svelte but it returns multiple errors
this is my main page code

```
    let username, password
    import {storage} from '../db/client/localStorage'
    import { writable, get} from 'svelte/store'
    import {checkSignIn} from '../db/server/checklogin'
    import Student from './student/Student.svelte'
    import Teacher from './teacher/Teacher.svelte'
    import Admin from './admin/Admin.svelte'
    export let {account} = writable(false)
    if(!storage.get('user') || !storage.get("password")){
    }
    else{ 
       account.set(checkSignIn(storage.get("user"), storage.get("password")))
    }
```

this is the code that uses an import:

```
import {account} from '../../components/page.svelte'
```

I get the error:
`app.js:16

```
   SyntaxError: The requested module '/src/components/page.svelte?t=1678030359672' does not provide an export named 'account' (at checklogin.js?t=1678030359672:4:9)`
```

I tried putting it into a 'let' but it does not seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not valid:

```js
export let {account} = writable(false)
```

If anything it should be

```js
export let account = writable(false)
```

But this will export this as *property* of the component which can only be used with component instances, e.g.

```html
<Page account={...} />
```

If you want to import/export a static variable, you have to do so from a [`<script context="module">`](https://svelte.dev/docs#component-format-script-context-module). E.g.

```html
<script context="module">
   export const account = writable(false);
</script>
```

Which then would be imported as a named import:

```js
import { account } from '../../components/page.svelte'
```

Note, that this *rarely makes any sense*. There will only be one instance of this variable, regardless of how many instances of the component exist. For a page component, of which there only ever will be one, this might be acceptable.